# Display 3 posts in one loop for a Carousel Slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, foreach, owl-carousel

I want to display three posts in one loop so I can use a carousel slider. In this way I can wrap all the three posts in the loop with a  so my carousel slider can see them as an item. How do I go about this? Here is my current loop:

```
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <h3 class="mgntop">LATEST NEWS</h3><br>
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <?php
            $newsposts = get_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=3');
            foreach($newsposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
            <div class="newswidth newsbox item">
                <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php
                        the_title();
                        ?>
                    </a></h6>
                <div class="boxelements">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"> </span>
                    <?php the_time(); ?>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                </p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="more-btn">read more</div>
                </a>
                <span class="fa fa-comments cmnt"> <?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,

   items : 1,
  // itemsDesktop : false,
  // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
  // itemsTablet: false,
  // itemsMobile : false
```

});

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

You try like this

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#oul-demo").owlCarousel({
          loop: true,
          item: 3,
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @D Coder This only shows one post per slide. What I want is 3 posts per slide.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to loop through the slide posts and put the casoural items inside the while loop

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'slide',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,

);
$slide = new WP_Query( $args );?><?php if ( $slide->have_posts() ):?>
<div id="maddy-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php $j=0; ?>
        <?php while ( $slide->have_posts() ) : $slide->the_post();?>
            <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
                <?php if($j==0): ?>
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <!-- // content -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <!-- // content -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $j++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#maddy-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#maddy-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

with foreach loop you can try

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'slide',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,

);
$slide = new WP_Query( $args );?><?php if ( $slide->have_posts() ):?>
<div id="maddy-slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php $j=0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($posts as $post):
            <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
                <?php if($j==0): ?>
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <!-- // content -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <!-- // content -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $j++; ?>
        <?php the_post();endforeach;?>

    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#maddy-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#maddy-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: This is a while loop, can you help implement this in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to solve your issue:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="mgntop">LATEST NEWS</h3><br>

        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

        <?php

            $pcount=1;
            $newsposts = get_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=3');

            foreach($newsposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
                      <?php if($pcount%3 ==1)
                                  {?>
                                <div class="newswidth newsbox item">
                               <?php } ?>


                    <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php
                        the_title();
                        ?>
                    </a></h6>

                <div class="boxelements">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"> </span> <?php the_time(); ?>
                </div>
                <p> <?php the_excerpt() ?></p>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="more-btn">read more</div></a>
                <span class="fa fa-comments cmnt"> <?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></span>

            <?php if($pcount%3==0)
                                 { ?>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>
        <?php  $pcount++;

endforeach; ?>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort! Only a post displays after updating my code to what you gave above. Still trying to figure out what is wrong

Comment: Check your jquery related to carousel. In jquery items value should be 1.

Comment: I have edited my post, it has the jQuery now. After setting item's value to 1, it is still showing only one post alongside the title of the second post. What I want is to display 3 posts per loop so I can scroll to see other posts in group of 3s. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes I copied your code as you posted. It shows only one post together with the title of the second post, instead of 3 posts at once. I am ready to supply you with more information if you want